# IE7 Debug Issue - Absolute Background

Tags: css, debugging, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I am having an issue in IE with a background issue for this page: http://vitaminjdesign.com/IAM/company/

In all browsers it appears correctly BUT in IE. In IE7, The div, .aboutbg is way off to the right. Here is my HTML

```
<div id="companywrap">
   <ul id="leftcol">
    <li>nav item</li>
    <li>nav item</li>
    <li>nav item</li>
   </ul>

   <div id="rightcol">
      <h1 class="title">Parker Homescape <span>Company Overview</span></h1>
      <div id="companytext">
    <a class="readmorehome" href="/press">VIEW PRESS & AWARDS</a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="aboutbg"></div>
</div>
```

Basically, the companywrap is relatively positioned and the the div .aboutbg is absolutely positioned with a negative z-index (so the background image is truly in the background). For some reason in IE& the background is displaying way off to the right.

THE SECOND ISSUE I am having is with the nav (ul id="leftcol"). Look at it in IE7 and you will see what I mean. There seems to be line breaks added in. Any ideas?

Comment: I may have just partially resolved the first issue (absolute background image). Now the background image is correctly placed but overlapping over the divider line and the footer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue: I don't even see a background in IE7, and I think it's due to the negative z-index. Your z-indexes are pretty wild - I'd avoid using negatives altogether.

edit: For example, try by setting your z-index on .aboutbg to 0, and start moving the rest of your indexes up from there. Also, I noticed you're using a class for aboutbg but there's only one instance of it. Why not use an id instead?

Second issue: I'm not sure, but perhaps try adding a specific line-height to ul#leftcol li - I didn't see anything in reset.css or style.css.

Comment: thanks, I got rid of all negative z-index, and then changed the footer div to have a relative position and a z index of 10, so they can follow the natural order of z-index

Comment: Still having an issue with the second problem, going to pose another SO question. THanks

Answer (score 0):

If I recall IE7 doesn't work well with negative z-index.  Or any z-index for that matter.

Give your companywrap div a z-index higher than the aboutbg div and change the aboutbg z-index to a positive number.